# Parsing out the contents within brackets using Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm sure this is simple and I'll probably be embarrassed to have this question in my profile but I can't seem to get this Regex correct.

I'm tring to extract just the digits from the last group of the following string:

> Properties[1].Securitymeasures[14].AdditionalSecurityType

so I want to have a regex that will return **14**

The Regex I have come up with is:

### \[(\d)+\]

However  - the match is returning "[14]"  - *including the brackets* and I do not understand why. I have surrounded the \d with parenthesis which should mean that this is the data I want to capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your regex is actually matching

1. An opening bracket
2. One or more consecutive digits
3. A closing bracket

So the fact that it returns the brackets is entirely correct.  If you debug the following

```
Regex.Match("Properties[1].Securitymeasures[14].AdditionalSecurityType",
            @"\[(\d)+\]")
     .Groups[1]
     .Value // equals '1'
```

You'll see that the \d is captured as a group (you put it in parens, after all).

What you want to do is use a "Positive Lookbehind" to specify that you are looking for one or more digits after a bracket.

```
(?<=\[)\d+
```

that says

1. Match one or more consecutive digits
2. That come immediately after an open bracket

You can bracket that with a Positive Lookahead, but if you are parsing integer indexes, then you can always expect there to be only digits within brackets and can skip the lookahead.

Comment: Aha!! I _knew_ I was being thick. I was getting confused between _matches_ and _groups_. The Match value was "[14]" but the Match.Groups[1].Value is "14" - without the brackets. As soon as I saw "Groups[1]" in your answer the lightbulb went on. The look-ahead example is really interesting as well and give me an other solution - many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])
```

`(?=\])` Positive lookahead, match `]`

`(?<=\[)` Positive lookbehind, match `[`

[Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vhda)